Problem Loading an Image File with Diatric Letters in Filepath
I have a JavaFX app that loads image files and performs certain manipulations on them.  I recently became aware of a problem in which on Windows machines, the app won't load and process images that have non-English letters in the filepaths (ex. å, ü, ó).
I'm assuming it's an encoding issue, but I'm having difficult nailing down where in the workflow to do a conversion.  Of note, this only happens on Windows.  Works fine on Mac, I'm assuming due to differences in the OS's default encoding.  This also makes it painstakingly slow to diagnose, as my IDE is on a Mac.
For example, here's a short bit of code in the load function, with some debugging inserted in an attempt to diagnose where the issue is first arising.
if (file != null) {
     try {
          //Get filename parts
          String[] fileComponents = FileChooserClass.FilePathComponents(file);
          String filepath = fileComponents[0];

          loadDebug2(filepath); // dialog window showing the filepath

          //Create a Mat of the image
          Mat originalMat = new Mat();
          try {
               originalMat = Imgcodecs.imread(filepath);   //fails here
               loadDebug(originalMat);  //if properly read from filepath, show stage displaying the image
          } catch (Exception e) {
               loadDebug2("exception");  //dialog to let me know if there was an exception in loading the image to a mat
          }

Using this short bit of code as an example, the filepath is properly shown in the debug dialog window, complete with diatric characters.
However, the mat isn't properly created from the filepath, and the exception dialog is triggered instead.
It's as if the app can't find the source file because of the encoding, but the filepath is displayed properly with the diatric characters.
Anyone have any ideas on how best to handle the encoding?

Can you show your error message? I opened a file name "embüase.gif" using the code from here and I did not have any issues. OpenJDK 12.0.2 JavaFX 21, Windows 11.

Also Windows 11 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)

In the larger code, there's catch statement that triggers a dialog with a custom error message, similar in function to the "exception" dialog in the code excerpt above.  That's the only error I get.  Without the custom error message, there's nothing – it simply never processes and displays the image.

I don't know what loadDebug2 is doing, but it looks like you need to do something like  System.out.println(e.toString());.

loadDebug2 simply opens a JavaFX stage and populates it with the word "exception" so I can see that there's been an error when the app is running in a deployed environment.

As stated earlier, you may want to do System.out.println(e.toString()) or loadDebug2(e.toString()); so that you can see what the issue is.

Thanks for that suggestion.  Here's the result (re-typed from a screenshot, so any typos are mine, not in the e printout):
CVException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.9.0) C:\GHA-OCV-1\_work\ci-gha-workflow\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave\.cpp:1121: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !image.empty() in function cv::imencode.
This would seem to indicate that despite the filepath displaying correctly with the non-English characters, the line that loads the image from file to a mat isn't able to find it.

Please post the complete exception with stacktrace in your question. Formatted please. Another questions: Is in your application ANYWHERE any third party hook implemented - any c++ things?
